# Symmetry in rock music scores

Tags: rock

This webpage is an interesting article on [symmetry in the scores of J.S. Bach](https://plus.maths.org/content/topology-music-m-bius-strip). Are there any examples in jazz bands or in rock/pop music?  If we exclude the prob rock bands of the late '60s and early '70s, because they specifically claimed inspiration from classical music (and they are a little boring).

Rock bands that I think *could* apply are those like Chicago or The Band or soul musicians like Curtis Mayfield or Stevie Wonder, or Duke Ellington from jazz, but it's difficult to search for scores on the Internet. I don't know, that's why I'm throwing out the question to see what other people think.